# v-avatar padding that allows for layered look on image?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make some of my `<v-avatar>` background exposed to look like a border of sorts on an image with a `postion:absolute;`.

[image]

```
<v-card>
    <v-img
        src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg"
        height="200px"
        style="overflow: visible;"
    >
        <v-avatar style=" background: blue; postion:absolute; left: 40%; top: 80% " rounded width="80px" class="pa-2" height="80px">
            <img width="80" height="80" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/lists/1.jpg">
        </v-avatar>
    </v-img>
</v-card>
```

The problem I'm having is that the image presents itself over the padding and the `background: blue;` doesn't show:

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/WNGQrGo?editors=1000)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `v-img` is inheriting `height` and `width` from `v-avatar` even if you add `height, width` to the `<v-img>`. So removing `pa-2` from `v-avatar` and adding `style="width: 64px; height: 64px"` (pa-2 = 8px padding, 80 - 8*2 = 64px) solves the issue.

Otherwise you would need to add `display: block/inline-block` to `v-avatar` but you would still need to override `<v-img>` style as it still would inherit `width/height` by default.